# How to fix the error System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException?

Tags: c#

No record is added to the table. These records are not duplicates and are not the pk  type

```
private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.CustomerName = txt_customername.Text.Trim();
    c.CustomerTel = txt_telcustomer.Text.Trim();
    c.CustomerAddress = txt_customeraddress.Text.Trim();
    c.StartDate = lbl_Data.Content.ToString();
    c.UserID = publicvariable.guserId;

    database.Customers.Add(c);
    database.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("مشتری جدید با موفقیت ثبت شد");
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more details about the exception? Isn't there any more info there about columns, connection or anything?

Comment: I want to register a new customer, but I'm faced with this

Comment: I plugged this column into the user column, but when I shut down this connection I'm still faced with this mess
 An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details.

Comment: I meant the inner exception, that the error states, maybe there are some details in the InnerException property. For example there may be a problem with the type of StartDate - maybe the db expects a DateTime instead of string.

Comment: Agree with Miklós, read the inner exception. When .NET says, "See inner exception for details" you should see the inner exception for details, it will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: the details say that:
{"Error retrieving values from ObjectStateEntry. See inner exception for details."}
how should I fix it?